# Another question on commutativity of special type of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Referring to this  [Commutativity of special type of permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991424/commutativity-of-special-type-of-permutations) , if  $p_1p_2=p_2p_1 , p_1 \ne p_2 , p_1 \ne p_2^{-1} $ , then is it true that  $U_1 \cap U_2=\phi$ ?

Comment: Of course not! Why don't you spend a few minutes looking for a counterexample - try $S_4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $S_6$, let $p_1=(1,2)(5,6)$ and $p_2=(3,4)(5,6)\neq p_1$. One can verify that $p_1p_2=p_2p_1=(1,2)(3,4)\neq e$. But, $U_1\cap U_2=\{5,6\} \neq \emptyset$.